# ant fileset dir exclude certain directory

Tags: ant

There are many questions on this topic but none of the answers are solving my problem. Starting this thread again to get fresh input.

I tried two different approaches for excluding B-dir and all its contents under A-dir/subdir. But none work. FYI, a-dir is under dir.src
1)

```
  <copy todir="${dir.classes}" excludes="A-dir/**/B-dir/**">
  <fileset dir="${dir.src}" >
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
  </copy>
```

2)

```
  <copy todir="${dir.classes}">
  <fileset dir="${dir.src}" >
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="A-dir/**/B-dir/**"/>
  </fileset>
  </copy>
```

I tried deleting all old jars and do a clean compile like someone suggested. But that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think it should probably be:

```
<copy todir="${dir.classes}">
<fileset dir="${dir.src}" >
  <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  <exclude name="**/A-dir/**/B-dir/**"/>
</fileset>
</copy>
```

Note the `**/A-dir/**` instead of `A-dir/**`.